# How to delete the prior word with VS Code terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In my standard MacOS terminal, alt+delete deletes to the prior word, but in the VS Code embedded terminal it deletes to the prior *space*. Bizarrely, alt+left correctly moves the cursor to the prior word. For example, given `foo bar.baz` before the cursor, alt+delete will delete `bar.baz` while alt+left will move the cursor to the start of `baz`. Is there a way to get the proper delete-word functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is deleteWordPartLeft which is bound to ^optionBkSpc on MacOS for me.

Comment: This works, but to fix the keybinding, you need the following:

`{"key": "alt+backspace", "command": "deleteWordPartLeft", "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly || terminalFocus"}`

Answer (score 7):

Update July, 2020 : for cmd.exe see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/98494

It looks like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will soon work to delete the word left.

---

More investigation with `sendSequence` **this works for me** (on bash) after I saw a comment elsewhere that said <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> worked to delete back to the last non-word character.

```
{
  "key": "alt+delete",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "\u001b\u007f" },   // delete word left to first non-word character
                                        //  =  escape+delete
  "when": "terminalFocus"
},
```

It doesn't also delete that now-trailing non-word character at the same time, you'll have to <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to clip that off.

---

In v1.45 is the ability to set the integrated terminal's word separators, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#control-double-click-word-selection
with this setting:

```
terminal.integrated.wordSeparators  // only affects double-click selections, not deletions
```

---

**UPDATE**:  Also in v1.45 terminal commands like `deleteWordLeft` have been removed.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#removal-of-several-prompt-related-commands

> The following commands have been removed:
>
> ```
> workbench.action.terminal.deleteWordLeft
> workbench.action.terminal.deleteWordRight
> workbench.action.terminal.deleteToLineStart
> workbench.action.terminal.moveToLineStart
> workbench.action.terminal.moveToLineEnd
> ```
>
> These commands worked by sending a particular character sequence to
> the terminal, which was a best effort guess based on what command
> keybindings terminals use. The problem with these commands was that
> they were a black box, you needed to literally search through the
> vscode codebase to figure out how they worked. They have been replaced
> with custom keybindings for the `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence`
> command, which does the same thing in a generic way.
>
> These are advanced keyboard shortcuts and cannot be viewed in their
> entirety via the Keyboard Shortcuts UI as they contain arguments but
> you can view their JSON definitions by running the Preferences: Open
> Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON) command:
>
> This should also help you learn how to use the [powerful `sendSequence`
> command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding).

To delete the word to the left in the terminal you would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

But that results in the same behaviour you don't want (deleting all of `bar.foo` instead of just `foo`), regardless of the the terminal wordSeparator setting - which only affects double-click selections not deletions unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

Combine what's suggested by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61063790/3682560) and [RxJx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58224177/3682560), set <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> to `deleteWordPartLeft` work's for me on macOS.

```
{
    "key": "alt+backspace",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.deleteWordPartLeft", 
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

The command you want is called `deleteWordEndLeft`.  From experimentation, this deletes, to the left, all contiguous non-whitespace characters, followed by all contiguous whitespace characters.

Before:

```
  this is some example text
                  ^
                cursor (to left of 'm')
```

After `deleteWordEndLeft`:

```
  this is somemple text
              ^
            cursor (to left of 'm')
```

Hopefully that's the behavior you want!  (Sorry for getting it wrong initially.)

To bind it, go into the key bindings (File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts) and use the search box to search for `deleteWordEndLeft`.  That will show you the existing key binding (if any; it is not bound by default on Windows).  You can change the keybinding by right-clicking on the binding and choosing Change Keybinding (if bound) or Add Keybinding (if not).

Comment: This is already bound to alt+delete which does the delete-to-previous-whitespace instead of the delete woe behavior as described in the question.

Comment: @weberc2 Whoops, sorry for misreading the question.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hmm, apparently VS Code has different shortcuts for the terminal and the main editor. I'm specifically referring the terminal, and the behavior that I want is to be able to delete just the last word, for example, in a URL: `curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824640/how-to-delete-the-prior-word-with-vs-code-terminal/57830840#57830840` If the cursor is at the end of that URL and I press `alt+backspace`, I would like it to read: `curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824640/how-to-delete-the-prior-word-with-vs-code-terminal/57830840#`.

Comment: Interestingly, the editor behaves properly, but the terminal does not.

Comment: @weberc2 From browsing the available commands (Ctrl+Shift+P, "Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"), it appears there is not a `deleteWordEndLeft` for the terminal, only `deleteWordLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

For bash I think it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

Comment: `ctrl+w` is different than `alt+delete` on my mac anyway. The former deletes to the prior whitespace (like `alt+delete` on vs code) while the latter deletes the last chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer by @mark in 2020, I was able to get this working, when the two documented methods didn't work.

What I wanted: When terminal has focus, `CMD+W` deletes word left, instead of closing the current open file ('editor') like a browser.

What didn't work:

1. `-workbench.action.closeActiveEditor` in the "Terminal: Commands To Skip Shell" section.
2. This code, in keybindings.json: (it gave me errors `command 'workbench.action.terminal.deleteWordPartLeft' not found`

   1. ```json
       {
         "key": "alt+backspace",
         "command": "workbench.action.terminal.deleteWordPartLeft", 
         "when": "terminalFocus"
       },
      ```
3. Checking the box for "Terminal: Send keybindings to shell"

What worked:

```json
    {
        "key": "cmd+w",                   // whatever keybinding you want
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": { "text": "\u001b\u007f" },   // delete word left to first non-word character
                                              //  =  escape+delete
        "when": "terminalFocus && isMac"
    }
```

Comment: Note: it was the same for `deleteWordLeft` and `deleteWordPartLeft`. both gave 'command not found' errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to delete a word to the left, up to a punctuation character ., /, etc. Here are the steps on Mac,
Shift + Command + p opens up the command palette. Type keybindings.json and add the following new binding in the json file

```
{
    "key": "alt+delete",                   // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "0x1B 0x08" },   // delete word left to first non-alphanumeric character
                                          //  =  escape+delete
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

Also you need to change the existing action for the alt+delete binding. To do so, go to Settings->Keyboard Shortcuts, find the existing entry for alt-delete by clicking on the Record Keys button, and change the keybinding to something else (e.g., ctrl+cmd+delete).